# phoenix connection namenode ha and hbase failed

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

some base info follow:

Hadoop2.7.1  and NameNode HA Enable
Hbase0.98.12
phoenix-4.6.0-HBase-0.98

execute sqlline.py localhost is error 
execute sqlline.py localhost:nameservices/hbase is error

phoenix don't support NameNode is HA Hadoop clusters ?
thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Apache Phoenix does not care your HDFS. You should give your zookeeper information which store hbase information.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to execute

->  bin/sqlline.py zookeeper-sever-name:2181 
in order to connect phoenix to ur Hbase instance.

If you have given the hbase z-node to register as /hbase1 then u need to provide the directory to sqlline. The command then would be like :

->  bin/sqlline.py zookeeper-sever-name:2181/hbase1

where zookeeper-server-name is the server where the zookeeper service has been started.
Hope this helps.